# jquery;-isvisibility using visible() how can i select the radio button of first visible tr

Tags: jquery, visibility

My table is like the following.  By using `visible()` how can I select the radio button of first visible `tr` on two different div's (hidden_source1 and hidden_source2)?  I already did it like this, first  whether the `tr` is visible and checked or not in two div's, second, if the visible `tr`is found click the radio in that div's.

```
<HTML>
<title></title>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<tab>$(document).ready(function(){
<tab>$("#hidden_source1").find( "input", ".rower:visible" )[0].checked = true;
<tab>$("#hidden_source1").find( "input", ".rower:visible" )[0].click
});
<tab>$(document).ready(function(){
<tab>$("#hidden_source2").find( "input", ".rower:visible" )[0].checked = true;
<tab>$("#hidden_source2").find( "input", ".rower:visible" )[0].click
});
</script>
</head>
<body> 
    <div id="hidden_source1">
<table id="return_me" class="tbl2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr class="rower" style="display: none;">
<td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="30">
<input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rower" style="display: none;">
<td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="30">
<input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rower" style="display: none;">
<td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="30">
<input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rower" style="display: table-row;">
<td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="30">
<input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rower" style="display: table-row;">
<td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="30">
<input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rower" style="display: table-row;">
<td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="30">
<input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="hidden_source2">
<table id="return_me" class="tbl2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr class="rower" style="display: none;">
<td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="30">
<input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rower" style="display: none;">
<td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="30">
<input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rower" style="display: none;">
<td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="30">
<input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rower" style="display: table-row;">
<td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="30">
<input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rower" style="display: table-row;">
<td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="30">
<input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rower" style="display: table-row;">
<td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="30">
<input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( 'div[id^="hidden_source"]' ).each(
        function(){
        $( ".rower:visible:first input", this ).prop( "checked", true );
        }
    );

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rB8EE/2/

You need to have different names for the radio inputs inside hidden_source1 and hidden_source2...

Comment: and i had one dout if there are two divs("#hidden_source1","#hidden_source2") i want to do same functionality in both div's i done like  (<script type="text/JavaScript">
<tab>$(document).ready(function(){
<tab>$("#hidden_source1").find( "input", ".rower:visible" )[0].checked = true;
<tab>$("#hidden_source1").find( "input", ".rower:visible" )[0].click
});
<tab>$(document).ready(function(){
<tab>$("#hidden_source2").find( "input", ".rower:visible" )[0].checked = true;
<tab>$("#hidden_source2").find( "input", ".rower:visible" )[0].click
});
</script>
) ..if you dont mine can you check this once

Comment: thank-you very much..and i tried like following it is also working$(document).ready(function(){

$('.tbl1').find('tr.rower:visible:first input').attr('checked', true);
$('.tbl2').find('tr.rower:visible:first input').attr('checked', true);});..it is also working...

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

```
$(function(){
    $('tr.rower:visible:first input').attr('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( 'div[id^="hidden_source"]' ).each(
        function(){
        $( ".rower:visible:first input", this ).prop( "checked", true );
        }
    );

});

(OR)

BY THE REFERENCE OF Mr.methodin'S ANSWER
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.tbl1').find('tr.rower:visible:first input').attr('checked', true);
$('.tbl2').find('tr.rower:visible:first input').attr('checked', true);

});
```